# How to prove that this $\limsup$ is equal to $1$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that this $\limsup$ is equal to $1$:

$$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0}-\frac{\log(\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]+1)}{\log \epsilon}=1.$$

where $[\cdot]$ is the integer part.

I tried the following:

as $\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]+1\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}+1$ we have to:

$$\begin{align}\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} -\frac{\log(\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]+1)}{\log \epsilon}&\leq \limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} - \frac{\log(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1)}{\log \epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} - \frac{\log(\frac{1}{\epsilon}+1)}{\log \epsilon} \\\\&\le \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \left[1 - \frac{\log(1+\epsilon)}{\log \epsilon}\right] = 1\end{align}$$

I would like to know how to prove that this $\limsup$ is equal to $1$. So I managed to show that it is equal to or less than $1$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at $\epsilon = 1/n$?

Comment: *Note:  I edited on two rows because the last $=1$ was not easily visible, so one (I did) could think OP was blocked on the last limit, which is not the case. Instead the question is about why the $\varlimsup=\lim$.*

Answer (score 2):

$\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]+1>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ hence $-\frac{\log\left(\left[\frac1\epsilon\right]+1\right)}{\log \epsilon}>1$ so $1$ is a lower bound for $\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0^+}-\frac{\log(\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]+1)}{\log \epsilon}.$ Since you already proved it is also an upper bound, you get equality.

Or more directly and precisely: as $\epsilon\to0^+,$ we have $\frac1\epsilon\to+\infty$ and
$\left[\frac1\epsilon\right]+1\sim\left[\frac1\epsilon\right]\sim\frac1\epsilon$ hence $\log\left(\left[\frac1\epsilon\right]+1\right)\sim\log\frac1\epsilon,$ so
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}-\frac{\log(\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]+1)}{\log \epsilon}=1.$$